# Android Google Map draw text and icon on overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

When I use the Overlay to draw text/icon on google map, I encounter a problem. It can only draw text but not icon. But for the text, while I pan the map (move the map around), the test stays at the same place (Actually, while moving map, the text can not move horizontally but can move vertically ).
Here is my code:

```
  class myRecommendationOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        List<Restaurant> restlist = new ArrayList<Restaurant>() ;

        public void setRestlist(List<Restaurant> ls)
        {
            restlist = ls;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            if(restlist.size() != 0)
            {      

                for(int i = 0; i < restlist.size(); i++)
                {
                    Point restaurantPoint = new Point();
                    GeoPoint tempPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(((Restaurant)restlist.get(i)).getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(((Restaurant)restlist.get(i)).getLongitude()*1E6));
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tempPoint, restaurantPoint);  
                    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
                    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                    mPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
                    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                    //Bitmap restIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.restaurant);
                    //canvas.drawBitmap(restIcon,restaurantPoint.x, restaurantPoint.y, null);
                    canvas.drawText(((Restaurant)restlist.get(i)).getName(), restaurantPoint.x , restaurantPoint.y, mPaint);
                }

            }       
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?